# fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to make sure an email exist/ doesn't exist in firebase, but the method I'm trying to use does not seem to work.

This is my current code:

```
export function checkEmail(email) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(checkEmailRequest());

    return window.firebase
      .auth()
      .fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email)
      .then(results => {
        dispatch(checkEmailSuccess(results));
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        dispatch(checkEmailFailed(error));
      });
  };
}
```

Message: TypeError: window.firebase.auth(...).fetchSignInMethodsForEmail is not a function

Comment: What does the following log? `console.log(window.firebase.auth())`? Do other `window.firebase.auth()` methods/properties work for in your project?

Comment: This is what it returns: vs {l: false, app: e, c: mr, N: Array(0), m: Array(2), …}
I haven't tried other functions with .auto(), but window.firebase.firestore functions work

Comment: How are you adding the `auth` module to your project exactly?

Comment: Not sure actually. Forgot to mention that I actually have used  window.firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) 

That too works fine

Comment: show me the line where you are importing all your firebase dependencies, basically where you are executing the start application method @MohammadSaad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess is that you're using an older version of the Firebase JavaScript SDK, while `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` was introduced in [version 6.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_600_-_may_7_2019). Before that it was called `fetchProvidersForEmail`. So you'll either have to upgrade to a later version of the SDK, or use the older method.

Comment: This works for me. Thnaks

Answer (score 1):

For the the new modular version it's done like this:

```
import { fetchSignInMethodsForEmail } from 'firebase/auth';

fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(auth, email).then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
});
```